# HTML llamar un formulario desde otro formulario en la misma pagina

Tags: html, form-submit

```
 <form name="update" action="" method="post">
    Nombre de Usuario
    <input name="txtbus" type="text">
    <input name="btn1" value="Buscar" type="submit">
</form>
<form class="contacto" name='contacto' method="POST" action="">
        <div><etiqueta>Nombre de Usuario:</etiqueta><input type='text' id="usuario" name="usuario"></div>
        <div><etiqueta>Empleado:</etiqueta><input type='text' id="nombre" name="nombre" ></div>
        <div>
            <a id="botoneditarusuario" class="button green" ><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Aceptar</a>
            <a id="cancelbuscar" class="button delete" type="reset">Cancelar</a>
        </div>  
</form>
```

La pregunta es: puedo llamar el formulario `contacto` al hacer click en el `submit` del formulario `update` ?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con mandar llamar?

Comment: hola, me refiero a abrir ese segundo formulario

Comment: prueba usando bootstrap , al que quieras llamar úsalo como modal , y asignarle al evento click del botón que realiza el submit que levante el modal del otro formulario, espero te sirva...

Comment: lo que quiere es tener dos formularios en la misma pagina para eso se utilizar un wizards, aqui le dejor un link  https://colorlib.com/wp/free-bootstrap-wizards/

Answer (score 1):

Si no he entendido mal la consulta, ya que no pones más código a parte del HTML ni explicas el funcionamiento completo, quieres mostrar el segundo formulario ya que se encuentra oculto en un principio.

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

> HTML

Lo he modificado añadiendo ID´s a los formularios para manejarlos de manera sencilla, agregado un action al formulario que llamará al script donde valides que existe. Además he quitado la etiqueta `<etiqueta> TEXTO </etiqueta>` que rodeaba los textos, ya que no es válida. También he añadido un `<div>` respuestas para mostrar mensajes.

```
<form name="update" action="script.php" method="post" id="updateU">
    Nombre de Usuario
    <input name="txtbus" type="text">
    <input name="btn1" value="Buscar" type="submit">
</form>
<form class="contacto" name='contacto' id="contactoU" method="POST" action="" style="display: none;">
    <div>Nombre de Usuario:<input type='text' id="usuario" name="usuario"></div>
    <div>Empleado:<input type='text' id="nombre" name="nombre" ></div>
    <div>
        <button id="botoneditarusuario" class="button green" ><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Aceptar</button>
        <button id="cancelbuscar" class="button delete" type="reset">Cancelar</button>
    </div>  
</form>
<div id="respuestas"></div>
```

> JQuery

He re-escrito el código que te puse, haciendo uso de Ajax para realizar la primera petición que busca si tu usuario existe en la DB y recoge los datos.

```
$("#updateU").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var datos = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        data: datos,
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#respuestas').html(''); //Reseteamos el contenido de respuestas.
        },
        success: function(res){
            if(res){
                var resData = JSON.parse(res);

                $('#usuario').val(resData[0]);
                $('#nombre').val(resData[1]);
                $("#contactoU").show();
            } 
            else $('#respuestas').html('Usuario no encontrado.');
        }
    });
});
```

> PHP

Simplemente he creado un PHP para poder realizar mis pruebas, como lo tenías cubierto es un PHP simple que ni conecta ni aplica seguridad ni nada. Solamente tener en cuenta que para hacer sencillo el manejo de la respuesta que llega mediante AJAX, devolvemos los datos en formato JSON.

```
<?php
//Como el usuario indica que tiene el php cubierto, no se realizan comprobaciones de seguridad etc.
$busqueda = $_POST['txtbus'];

//Falseamos la consulta a DB etc para un ejemplo sencillo
$usuarios = array('jonilgz' => 'Jonatan', 'hgarcia' => 'H?');
if(array_key_exists($busqueda, $usuarios)){
    $res = array($busqueda, $usuarios[$busqueda]);
    echo json_encode($res);  
}else echo false;
```

Con esto tendrás una base para partir de ella, después ya queda trabajar el segundo formulario para enviar datos y demás.

Espero que te sirva, Saludos.

Comment: hola @jonilgz, efectivamente el formulario `update` tiene una busqueda mysql en php para ubicar un registro, si lo encuentra,debe mostrar los datos asociados en el fomulario `contacto` para poder editarlo, solo coloqué parte del codigo porque lo que me interesa ahora es saber si puedo mostrar el segundo formulario desde el `submit` del primero, gracias

Comment: la parte del codigo PHP lo tengo cubierto

Comment: Hola @HGarcia he actualizado la entrada con la información que me indicaste.

Answer (score 0):

Con el atributo form del input button puedes hacerlo, sin javascript.

```html
<form name="update" id="frmUpdate" action="" method="post">
    Nombre de Usuario
    <input name="txtbus" type="text" required="required">
    <input name="btn1" value="Buscar" type="submit">
</form>
<form class="contacto" name='contacto' id="frmcontacto" method="POST" action="">
        <div><etiqueta>Nombre de Usuario:</etiqueta><input type='text' id="usuario" name="usuario"></div>
        <div><etiqueta>Empleado:</etiqueta><input type='text' id="nombre" name="nombre" ></div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" form = "frmUpdate" id="botoneditarusuario" class="button green" ><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Aceptar</button>
            <button type="clear" id="cancelbuscar" class="button delete" type="reset">Cancelar</button>
        </div>  
</form>
```